# Firefox did not open the youtube

Tags: firefox, 18.04

For some reason i have tried to open youtube.com from terminal and left out with this result.

> user@user:~$ firefox www.youtube.com
>   [Parent 3633, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (76): Connection reset by peer: file /build/firefox-dpNVrZ/firefox-59.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 353

This warning is strength for me and why it linked with chrome browser ?
Thank You.

Comment: firefox does open youtube.

Comment: @anjanik012, mine show above error.